# How to set the root namespace in project.json for .NET Core?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

In a typical .NET Framework application, you would set the root namespace in the `<RootNamespace>` property of the `.csproj` file, which then flows through to set the root namespace for things like embedded resources.

In the .NET Core world (as of RC2), how do you set the root namespace in `project.json` to achieve the same result at runtime?

Comment: I don't think .Net Core has embedded resources with generated code, so it doesn't need root namespace for that. Why exactly do you need it?

Comment: The reason I need it is to correctly commute the names of embedded resources: https://github.com/martincostello/project-euler/blob/dot-net-core/src/ProjectEuler/Puzzle.cs#L93-L96

Answer (score 0):

The root namespace is a concept in Visual Studio to automatically create a namespace when you scaffold a class file (from the templates). You can find the setting in the .xproj files for .NET Core projects (since they are the bridge between Visual Studio and .NET Core tooling).

Other editors which can edit .NET Core projects (like Atom or similar) use their own scaffolding technique and do not have the concept of a "root namespace" (and also do not use the .xproj file). Therefore, there is no need for a setting in project.json.

In regards of resource usage: [Image as resource in Asp.Net 5 class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972571/image-as-resource-in-asp-net-5-class-library)

ps: Since .xproj is a msbuild file and Microsoft switches to msbuild for the final .NET Core tooling, that answer might get outdated (but I guess not since scaffolding is not a msbuild story).

Comment: Specifically I'm trying to find a way to workaround this difference between .NET Franework and .NET Core with regards to the name of embedded resources: https://github.com/martincostello/project-euler/blob/dot-net-core/src/ProjectEuler/Puzzle.cs#L93-L96

Comment: I see your problem. It looks like a difference between msbuild and the project.json implementation. I think there is not a fix, except maybe messing in your root namespace in the csproj (to emulate the same resource identifier string). Good thing for you: Will solve itself with time, since .NET Core will switch to msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right click your project and select "Properties"
In "Application" section, "General" subsection, edit the textbox under "Default namespace"
Its value is set by default to $(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_")), which uses the project name with normalized spaces, but you may choose another value (with no blank spaces).